# Name this collection

Tags: java, collections

This question is language-agnostic (although it assumes one that is both procedural and OO).

I'm having trouble finding if there is a standard name for a collection with the following behavior:

-Fixed-capacity of N elements, maintaining insertion order.

-Elements are added to the 'Tail'

-Whenever an item is added, the head of the collection is returned (FIFO), although not necessarily removed.

-If the collection now contains more than N elements, the Head is removed - otherwise it remains in the collection (now having advanced one step further towards its ultimate removal).

I often use this structure to keep a running count - i.e. the frame length of the past N frames, so as to provide  'moving window' across which I can average, sum, etc.

Comment: If no name is discovered, I'd like to suggest that it be called "Frank".

Comment: Though, if I had to implement something of the sort, I'd call it a "SlidingWindowQueue" or a "FixedLengthQueue".

Comment: How can I add and remove elements from a Collection with a fixed length?

Comment: I typically reference it as a RunningList (or MovingAverage, if the implementation's purpose is to provide the average over the window), but Frank does have a certain ring to it.

Comment: Since it has a fixed capacity and you can not overflow it then I would name it a NonOverflowableQueue

Comment: Frank is a great data structure name.  It's short, honest, and to the point. :)

Comment: @M. Reif I meant 'fixed capacity' - thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds very similar to a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) to me; with the exception that you are probably under-defining or over constraining the add / remove behavior.

Note that there are two "views" of a circular buffer.  One is the layout view, which has a section of memory being written to with "head" and "tail" indexes and a bit of logic to "wrap" around when the tail is "before" the head.  The other is a "logical" view where you have a queue that's not exposing how it is being laid out, but definately has a limited number of slots which it can "grow to".

Within the context of doing computation, there is a very long standing project that I love (although the cli interface is a bit foreign if you're not use to such things).  It's called the [RoundRobinDatabase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool), where each databases stores exactly N copies of a single value (providing graphs, averages, etc).  It adjusts the next bin based on a number of parameters, but most often it advances bins based on time.  It's often the tool behind a large number of network throughput graphs, and it has configurable bin collision resolution, etc.

In general, algorithims that are sensitive to the last "some number" of entries are often called "sliding box" algorithms, but that's focusing on the algorithm and not on the data structure :)

Comment: Yup, also called a "ring buffer" (the name I know it by) or "circular queue" or probably several other names.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've heard it called a ring buffer too.  Probably another one of the "multiple names for the same thing" issues that crop up in some of the early data structure terminology.  Kind of like "map" and "dictionary" (and I'm pretty happy that barely anyone refers to maps as dictionaries any more)

Comment: Any known difference (other than the names!) between a ring buffer / circular queue / circular linked list?

Comment: @EdwinBuck Sliding Box algorithm, indeed, although my use cases tend to be much simpler (running averages, mins, maxes... 'integrating' mouse movement over several frames, etc)

Comment: @bfishman There are no real differences.  Hardware implementations tended to call them ring buffers, people who were more concerned with the ordering aspects as opposed to the buffering aspects favored queue over buffer.  In short, all the implementations are more or less conceptually the same, but the names come from different areas of development / different common naming practices in different languages / different countries / etc.

Comment: Great response, thank you. I think ring buffer / circular queue is *slightly* closer to what I'm trying to describe (although implementation wasn't indicated in my question), especially because my collection is typically backed by an Array, not a Linked List.

Comment: @bfishman I found a link for the source code of frameCounter. You can take a look at it. I added it in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The programming riddle sounds like a **[circular linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly_linked_vs._linearly_linked)** to me.

Well, all these description fits, doesn't it?

• Fixed-capacity of N elements, maintaining insertion order.

• Elements are added to the 'Tail'

• Whenever an item is added, the head of the collection is returned (FIFO), although not necessarily removed.

---

This link with source codes for counting frames probably helps too: **[frameCounter](http://forum.selur.de/topic12-framecounter-counting-frames-in-raw-streams-source.html)**

Comment: This might be it - doing a bit more research on it!

Comment: Very close, thank you for your answer. From the question, which didn't discuss implementation in detail, your answer is just as good as the selected answer, circular buffer / queue. But since I'm backing it by an array, not a linked list (you had no way of knowing this), I selected the other answer for their better mind-reading powers.

Comment: Lists in general support insertion and removal from any position.  Circular linked lists were fun optimizations of regular linked lists because you didn't have to check if the next pointer was null.  Instead you checked if the next pointer was the same as the head pointer (which you had to store anyway to have a "handle" to the list.  It removed one constant from the code, and made the nesting of if statements a bit cleaner.  That said, they were very much used as lists (insert / remove at any position) (and with care any list can be used as a queue).